# Sitecore Scheduling Parameters

Tags: c#, sitecore, job-scheduling

**Problem**

I'm currently trying to setup a Sitecore scheduled task in the database using Schedules and Commands.

So far I've followed http://sdn.sitecore.net/FAQ/Administration/Scheduled%20tasks.aspx for most of what I've needed.  Their method uses:`public void WriteToLogFile(Item[] itemArray, CommandItem commandItem, ScheduleItem scheduledItem)`. I'm assuming that is the items passed in the schedule item, the command item itself, and the schedule item itself.

I have a run function which follows the same syntax: `protected void run(Item[] itemArray, CommandItem commandItem, ScheduleItem scheduleditem)`.  I've recieveing an exception as it runs in my logs though. Linked is the exception stack: http://pastie.org/1847345, but here is the nested exception:

```
Exception: System.NullReferenceException 
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Source: fhservices at fhservices.twitterPull.run(Item[] itemArray, CommandItem commandItem, ScheduleItem scheduleditem)
```

I've tried a few different combinations of parameters to accept with no luck.

**Scheduling web.config Section:**

```
 <scheduling>
  <!-- Time between checking for scheduled tasks waiting to execute -->
  <frequency>00:01:00</frequency>
  <!-- Agent to process schedules embedded as items in a database -->
  <agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent" method="Run" interval="00:02:00">
    <param desc="database">core</param>
    <param desc="schedule root">/sitecore/system/tasks/schedules</param>
    <LogActivity>true</LogActivity>
  </agent>
 ...
```

***Would anyone know the parameters that sitecore sends with methods which are invoked through this method of starting jobs?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the snippet you linked to on the SDN, I think you create your own method, similar to `WriteToLogFile` but not `Run()`. Step 4 says:

> Fill in the necessary fields:
>
> **Type**: CustomScheduleTasks.Task1, CustomScheduleTasks
>
> **Method**: WriteToLogFile
>
> The Type indicates the namespace and assembly file.  The Method indicates the method to call on the specified class.
>
> Your command is now ready for use as a scheduled task.

So instead of your `Run()` method, name it something else and set it in the `Method` field of the command in Sitecore. `Run()` is the method in the DatabaseAgent from Sitecore that runs.

Comment: I changed it to something else for the sake of just not being a possible reserved word. We'll see how it goes.

Comment: To be honest, I think this might have solved it? 
1. I changed the method named to pull
2. I changed it in the related command. 
3. Had an issue because I believe that VS was not building a debug version.
4. Replaced file with correct build. 
5. Went to try to setup breakpoint debugging and added reference to my Sitecore project.
6. Went to item to check if it ran, it had.
7. Looked at the log and it was successful all of the way through. - No other code was changed besides the name and related command.

Not really sure if it was 'run' or not but this seemed to fix it.

Comment: I forgot to note an important change. I feel foolish. The method I was calling was protected instead of public (left over from a copy & paste of an old Page_Load method).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your task is actually running. The exception doesn't mention anything about not being able to find your method and the exception comes from your tasks method. Try setting a breakpoint inside the method and checking what object is null.

Just for reference, the parameters passed to a scheduled task are the items specified in the items field of the command, the command definition item and the schedule definition item.

Comment: That's what I thought. Dumb question maybe, but I'm rather new to .Net. It's a compiled DLL outside of the project, is there a way I can still set a breakpoint and be able to debug? 
Guess I'm hung on this and wouldn't have had to ask if I could do this.

Comment: Alistair, I am still interested in finding out how I would go about debugging .dlls in my project with Sitecore if decide to write up a blog post or send a personal email, I would be entirely grateful. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Yes, you can easily debug this.  Just make sure you are doing a debug build so you get the .pdb file in the bin directory with your DLL.  Those are the debug symbols the debugger needs.  Then in Visual Studio use "Attach To Process" and attach to your ASP.NET worker process... this will vary depending on your IIS version.  Now set your breakpoints and voila.

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply Alex. I thought SO would email me if someone commented on my response. Anyway, Bryan described the process above for debugging into a DLL which is not part of your main project. The key is to attach to process rather than start the debugger with F5.

Answer (score 0):

Well... your method definition says "run", little r.  But in web.config you've got Run, big R.  Sitecore is using .Net reflection here to find the method, so it will be case-sensitive.

I have my scheduled tasks set up in System/Tasks rather than web.config.  Works like a charm.

Comment: Aye. I am using System/Tasks as well to be honest. I believe there is something in my code that is wrong. 

My task was set to a 'run' method as well. The capital 'R' was only the agent for the DatabaseAgent which Sitecore runs all the System/Tasks through. 

If you can answer the question in response to Alistar's answer, it might help me out if you know how to do that.

Thanks!